# RAW images taken in iOS 13 not visible in Image Capture or Lightroom on macOS?

Tags: photos, ios

I have a brand-new iPhone 11 Pro and have used [Halide](https://halide.cam) to take some photos in RAW format. My standard method for processing is to plug the phone into my iMac (currently running 10.14.6) and import them into Lightroom then edit from there. However, anything I shoot in RAW *will not show up* in Image Capture *or* Lightroom. I've tested under Catalina and Mojave, and my wife used Obscura to take some RAW photos on a recent trip with her iPhone 7 also running iOS 13.2, and is having the exact same problem.

Has anyone else a) run into this, and b) managed to fix it? It's *supremely* irritating. :(

Comment: I am running iOS 13.2 on an iPhone 7 and I can't save photos as RAW on any app. Usually there's a little button on top that says RAW when it's a raw photo. I have multiple apps that save as raw and none of them are working. Seems like a bug but I can't find anything about this online

Comment: Oh that's even weirder! I'm definitely getting RAW files saved as RAW at least, heh. Darkroom shows the little "R" next to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug that's since been resolved between either the macOS and/or iOS updates in recent months, I just checked now and can't replicate this behaviour anymore.